# Could not load file or assembly 'Elasticsearch.Net' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, nest

I've recently upgraded from NEST 1.9 to NEST 2.3. From some reason the assemblies in .NET have not been updated and are still looking for ElasticSearch.net package `Elasticsearch.Net, Version=1.0.0.0`

I've tried uninstalling then installing ElasticSearch.net and then NEST after which I restarted Visual Studio 4.6. I use .NET 45.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Elasticsearch.Net' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Elasticsearch.Net' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Elasticsearch.Net' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Elasticsearch.Net  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was
>   supplied for an assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: Elasticsearch.Net |
>   Domain ID: 2 WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly
>   display name is provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading
>   an incorrect assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully
>   specified textual identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the
>   simple name, version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See
>   whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more
>   information and common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/wht/We Heart Tours/wht/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\wht\We Heart Tours\wht\bin Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\wht\We Heart Tours\wht\web.config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\amocanu\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/amocanu/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/412255cb/fee8480d/Elasticsearch.Net.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/amocanu/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/412255cb/fee8480d/Elasticsearch.Net/Elasticsearch.Net.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/wht/We Heart
>   Tours/wht/bin/Elasticsearch.Net.DLL. LOG: Using application
>   configuration file: C:\wht\We Heart Tours\wht\web.config LOG: Using
>   host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\amocanu\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 2.0.0.0
>   redirected to 1.0.0.0. LOG: Post-policy reference: Elasticsearch.Net,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96c599bbe3e70f5d LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/amocanu/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/412255cb/fee8480d/Elasticsearch.Net.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/amocanu/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/412255cb/fee8480d/Elasticsearch.Net/Elasticsearch.Net.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/wht/We Heart
>   Tours/wht/bin/Elasticsearch.Net.DLL. WRN: Comparing the assembly name
>   resulted in the mismatch: Major Version ERR: Failed to complete setup
>   of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Elasticsearch.Net' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Elasticsearch.Net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=96c599bbe3e70f5d' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]

Comment: We had this problem, when we missed Newtonsoft.Json dll. Check, it.

Comment: @Backs how should I proceed? I don't quite understand your suggestion. Thanks for your answer though! Much appreciated. Wait, are you saying reinstall some higher version of Newtonsoft as well? Which version should I get?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone,
the solution is to edit `Web.config` and change

```
   <assemblyIdentity name="Elasticsearch.Net" publicKeyToken="96c599bbe3e70f5d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
```

to

```
   <assemblyIdentity name="Elasticsearch.Net" publicKeyToken="96c599bbe3e70f5d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
```

Comment: I reckon you can remove the binding redirect altogether; you **don't** want to use version 1.x as it was before, and there should be no need to specify binding to 2.x

Answer (score 1):

This error normally happens when you have two `Elasticsearch.Net` dependencies with different versions. In my case, it happened because I imported the `Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch` package in a project which already had the `Elasticsearch.Net` and `NEST` packages. As `Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch` and `NEST` packages have `Elasticsearch.Net` as a dependency, they need to be in the same version. I updated the `Elasticsearch.Net` and `NEST` packages to solve this problem.

This was the `.csproj` configuration before:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch" Version="8.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Elasticsearch.Net" Version="7.0.1" />
```

This is the solution:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch" Version="8.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="7.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Elasticsearch.Net" Version="7.9.0" />
```

It's important to check the NuGet reference to get information about the imported package dependencies: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nest , https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.ElasticSearch , https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elasticsearch.Net .